# Dafny, assigning sequence slice to array

Tags: z3, verification, dafny

in my Dafny program, I have an array `input:array?<int>` with an even length which I want to slice it into two equal parts and sort them individually and merge afterward in swiped order. (*insertion sort on an array of ints already implemented and verifies*). the slicing and merging in Dafny with `seq<int>` is easy and a complete documentation for it in [rise4fun](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/tutorial/Sequences). but I could not find an easy approach for arrays. What is the easiest way to do the same as sequences with an array?

```
        method MySort(input:array?<int>)
        { var mid:= input.Length/2;
          var subOne := input[0..mid];
          var subTwo := input[mid..input.Length];
          insertionSort(subOne); // ofcourse ERROR as insertion sort is implemented for array<int>
          insertionSort(subTwo); // ofcourse ERROR as insertion sort is implemented for array<int>
          input := subTwo + subOne;
        }
```

the complete code is [here in rise4fun](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/iJsli), in this code I have commented out the sequence approch and made some slicing with while loop. if this is the best way to do how should I do the concatination afterward.

Also [Here](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/qGfM) I have made the sorting method with `seq<int>` but at the swapping part (`input[j := b]; input[j-1 := a];`) also I get `expected method call, found expression`. According to the tutorial `input[j:=b]` should replace index j of seq input with the value of b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is assign the output of the `insertionSort` method to a variable like this:

```
subOne := insertionSort(subOne); 
subTwo := insertionSort(subTwo);
```

Now you will have a problem on the next line

```
input := subTwo + subOne;
```

because

```
subOne + subTwo
```

is a sequence, but `input` is a pointer to an array.  You don't want to change the pointer, you want to change the contents of the array.  One way to do that is shown below:

```
method probOneSort(input:array?<int>) 
modifies input;
requires input != null;
requires input.Length > 0;
requires input.Length%2==0;
{
 var mid:= input.Length/2;

 var subOne := input[0..mid];
 var subTwo := input[mid..input.Length];

 subOne := insertionSort(subOne);
 subTwo := insertionSort(subTwo);

 var val := subOne + subTwo ;
 forall i | 0 <= i && i < input.Length { input[i] := val[i] ; }
}
```

For this to verify, you need that `insertionSort` ensures that the length of its output is the same as the length of its input. Otherwise the verifier can not verify that the subscript `val[i]` is in range.

Comment: is it generally better to change the insertion sort to sequence (which now I have face mutability problems and violation of functions). or keep it as array<int> and change the approach in the probOneSort method?
code samples one or two ? which is better?

Comment: For efficiency using arrays will give a more efficient algorithm. For verification, sequences are a bit simpler becuase arrays give indirect access to locations; that means you have to learn about `reads` and `modifies` in order to use arrays.